# GDI+ DC in memory always monochrome

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Working in mingw, having a terrible time creating a color DC in memory.  For instance, in the following code snippet, as written, "foo_scratch.bmp" is a monochrome version of the 
image (from an EMR_STRETCHDIBITS record).  If instead aDC is omitted and srcDC uses the CreateDC directly, then that file has a color image.

```
        Gdiplus::Bitmap *pbmp = NULL;

        BITMAPINFO *pbitmapinfo = (BITMAPINFO *)((char *)lpEMFR + pEmr->offBmiSrc);
        void *pBitsInMem = (char *)lpEMFR + pEmr->offBitsSrc;
        HBITMAP hbmsrc;
        HDC aDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", "", NULL, NULL);
        HDC srcDC = CreateCompatibleDC(aDC);
        hbmsrc = CreateDIBitmap(
            srcDC,
            &(pbitmapinfo->bmiHeader),
            CBM_INIT,
            pBitsInMem,
            pbitmapinfo,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        if(hbmsrc){

          CLSID pngClsid;
          GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &pngClsid);
            pbmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hbmsrc,NULL);
            pbmp->Save(L"C:\\Temp\\foo_scratch.bmp",&pngClsid, NULL);
```

This all comes to a head later when two images (hbmdst, hbmsrc) need to be put together with a bitblt operation.  At present the best I have managed is monochrome.  At worst the image is solid black.  In this snippet the ROP has been hard coded to SRCCOPY, and I still have not succeeded in just copying the image from one HBITMAP to another.  Very frustrating!

```
          HDC dstDC = CreateCompatibleDC(aDC);
          HBITMAP hbmdOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(dstDC, hbmdst);
          HBITMAP hbmsOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(srcDC, hbmsrc);
          GetObject(hbmsrc, sizeof(bm), &bm);
          BitBlt(dstDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, srcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
          SelectObject(srcDC, hbmsOld);
          SelectObject(dstDC, hbmdOld);
          (void) DeleteDC(dstDC);
          pbmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hbmdst,NULL);
          pbmp->Save(L"C:\\Temp\\scratch.bmp",&pngClsid, NULL);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - wherever a bitmap is created have to use the DC directly associated with the display (or other device), not the "compatible" DC derived from the first DC.